Suma de los elementos de dos listas
Intento sumar los elementos de dos listas ingresadas por teclado, con el siguiente código, pero me da el error que transcribo abajo. Si ingreso las listas en el mismo código, sí funciona. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
#Toma dos tuplas o listas y retorna una nueva con la suma de sus miembros
string_entrada_1 = input("Ingresa la lista o tupla 1: ")

#lista1 = string_entrada_1.split()

lista1 = list(string_entrada_1)

print(lista1)

string_entrada_2 = input("Ingresa la lista o tupla 2: ")

#lista2 = string_entrada_2.split()

lista2 = list(string_entrada_2)

print(lista2)

print()
"""
lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lista2 = [6, 7, 8, 9]
"""

resultado = [sum(i) for i in zip(lista1, lista2)]

print('La suma de los elementos de las listas ingresadas es: ', resultado)

ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "/Users/victor/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-

Personal/Cursos/Python/curso_python/Ejercicios/array_sum_1.py", line 17, in <module>
    
  resultado = [sum(i) for i in zip(lista1, lista2)]

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'


supongo que el lenguaje es python???

lista1 = list(string_entrada_1)

string_entrada_1 es un string. Cuando aplicas la función list, se genera una lista cuyos elementos son los caracteres del string.
Si el string es "1 2 3", entonces lista1 es ['1', ' ', '2', ' ', '3']. Es una lista de string, no de valores numéricos. También tiene elementos inútiles (los espacios).
Una manera de generar la lista de enteros es
lista1 = [int(x) for x in string_entrada_1.split()]

Con el método split() divides el string por los espacios, y con int() transformas cada caracter numérico en su valor entero.
Aplicado a 1 2 3, produce [1, 2, 3].
Para sumar no necesitas sum(), basta con sumar directamente los elementos de la tupla
resultado = [tupla[0] + tupla[1] for tupla in zip(lista1, lista2)]

Código completo
string_entrada_1 = input("Ingresa la lista o tupla 1: ")
lista1 = [int(x) for x in string_entrada_1.split()]
print(lista1)
string_entrada_2 = input("Ingresa la lista o tupla 2: ")
lista2 = [int(x) for x in string_entrada_2.split()]
print(lista2)
print()
""" lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] lista2 = [6, 7, 8, 9] """
resultado = [tupla[0] + tupla[1] for tupla in zip(lista1, lista2)]
print('La suma de los elementos de las listas ingresadas es: ', resultado)

produce
Ingresa la lista o tupla 1: 1 2 3
[1, 2, 3]
Ingresa la lista o tupla 2: 4 5 6
[4, 5, 6]

La suma de los elementos de las listas ingresadas es:  [5, 7, 9]


No sientes que tu respuesta es la misma de ayer? Parece que Victor no está aprendiendo de sus errores. El problema es el mismo

@Mateo No me había dado cuenta. Por otra parte, es el nivel de problemas que se plantea en este sitio.
